# How to require index.php of third party which also requires stuff

Tags: php, routes, include, require

I've got this problem:

In `pseudoRoot/Dir/api/index.php` I have:

```
<php
    require "SomeFolder/index.php";
?>
```

In `pseudoRoot/Dir/api/SomeFolder/index.php` I have:

```
<php
    require "SomeDeepFolder/someScript.php";
?>
```

where `pseudoRoot/Dir/api/SomeFolder/SomeDeepFolder/someScript.php`.

Now everything in `SomeFolder` is some 3-rd party lib that I don't want to mess with and the requires/includes there are as in the pseudo for `SomeFolder/index.php` above. Calling `pseudoRoot/Dir/api/index.php` leads to error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. As far as I understood this has to do with the weird way PHP handles relative paths (the second require/include has the first one file's relative path instead his own) but how can I make this kind of routing work without having to mess around with the lib's files meaning not touching anything in `.../SomeFolder` and working only with `.../api/index.php`? I've tried using `require dirname(__FILE__) . /SomeFolder/index.php` with no success.

Ah, and the "flow" reaches `pseudoRoot/Dir/api/index.php` through a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` routing all requests to it.

Sorry if question is duplicate, couldn't find any answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Composer, it will handle the requires for you.

Instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` you can also you use `__DIR__`. But it's returning the directory of the current file.

Using `__DIR__` should work as long as the added part is related to the current directory. You can also save this once as a `$rootDirectory` and use this to load all files related to this root directory.

```
<?php
dirname(__DIR__, 1); // the extra parameter is for getting a level (or more) up from the current directory.
?>
```

Comment: *Composer* is designed to autoload classes not scripts!

Comment: You would like to change the PHP language. It is designed to run from the first file you enter. Includes are relative to that file.

What's the reason for not changing the 3th party lib? And shouldn't it use Composer for autoloading the classes?

Comment: The lib is not the problem, I guess I'm the problem :D Testing out and learning PHP on the go, obviously what I want is impossible and my approach was wrong from the very beginning. I don't even have some sort of framework/architecture yet, just trying to tide up and secure my code a bit.